# How to split a single feature vector into a layer of 2 neurons

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

Given an array `x = [1, 2, 3, ...]` , I want to split each sample `x[i]` into 2 neurons.

My idea was to initialize a variable `split = np.random.rand()` with $0 < split < 1$

and then set the neurons `x1 = split * x[i], x2 = (1 - split) * x[i]`.

Is my idea correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea sounds good to me. By initializing the split variable with a random number between 0 and 1, and then splitting each sample into two neurons using that split value, you'll be randomly allocating the feature of each sample between two neurons. This can help your network to learn more complex and diverse representations of the data. However, keep in mind that splitting the samples in this way might not always be the best approach depending on your specific problem and the type of data you're working with. Overall, I think it's a good idea and worth trying out to see how it works for your particular use case.